# Can a gas safety check be carried out when the boiler will not light?

Tags: boiler

My gas safety check is due and my landlord has said it has to be done on Saturday

I've had issues with the boiler not lighting for a long time, but usually if it is left for a while it will eventually work, however, since before Christmas is has gotten worse and now would go off for days.

It has now been off for two days and I can't seem to get it to come back on, we have no heating or hot water and I can't afford to get a plumber out until I get paid next week.

The gas check was due months ago and when I threatened to report him if it wasn't done the landlord said he will evict me if it is not done this weekend as I am preventing him from carrying out the check. (I've told him they can come any week day as I only work weekends, but his plumber friend will only do it on a Saturday)

With the boiler not lighting it obviously can't be tested, it's the only gas appliance I have, so there is just that and the gas meter to check.

I'm really panicking as I don't want to be evicted, it's not exactly my fault that the boiler isn't working.

I've told the landlord about the problems with it but he doesn't care and said he can't see a problem and if I want to call someone out it's my choice and responsibility to pay for.

It was off for five days over Christmas but when the landlord finally returned my calls it had started working again so he refused to send someone to look at a 'perfectly working boiler'.

It's a combi boiler by the way and the fault with it is that it says 'flame loss'. 
I have tried reseting it and all of the advice I can find online but nothing works and it won't ignite.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like the landlord has no respect for you as a tenant.  It is not your responsibility to repair the boiler and in most locations in the US if the tenant is forced to make necessary repairs to make the home livable they can either charge the landlord or deduct it from there rent.  Some areas allow you to withhold rent until a repair is completed.  You should have a office in your county where you can direct rental related questions.

Comment: here is a web reference to review:  http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/renters-rights-book/chapter7-5.html